# Dynamic Cumulative Totals on Pivoted Table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, pivot, dax, slicers

I have a table of hire and exit dates for staff, along with characteristics that describe the staff, such as gender and education level. Each row represents a staff member.  My goal is to create a dashboard that shows the cumulative number of staff by characteristics. Users should be able to select a characteristic with a slicer and see an updated cumulative total staff count as a line graph.

I began by pivoting my staff records so that multiple attributes are available, as shown below.

[image]

To compute cumulative staff totals by year, I used the following DAX command:

```
CumulativeStaffTotal2 = CALCULATE(  SUM(Merge1[netchange]), ALLEXCEPT(Merge1, Merge1[Value]), Merge1[year]<=EARLIER(Merge1[year]))
```

This command, however, does not yield accurate results.

How do I design a solution that calculates a cumulative total that is responsive to inputs from a slicer that shows different attributes (e.g. gender, ed level) on a pivoted table?

Answer (score 0):

You accomplish this using [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) function, a solution would be like:

```
CumulativeStaffTotal2 = CALCULATE(  SUM(Merge1[netchange]), FILTER(ALL(Merge1[year]), Merge1[year]<=MAX(Merge1[year])))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Dordi, but your solution throws an error:  A function 'MAX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Comment: @Ben, Try this, i added Filter because we have 2 conditions in calculate statemnet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffTotal2 = CALCULATE(  SUM(Merge1[netchange]), FILTER(ALL(Merge1[year]), Merge1[year]<=MAX(Merge1[year])))
```

Basically,you have to use FILTER() to compare a column value ( Merge1[year] ) to a measure(MAX(Merge1[Year]))